# Jtable cant load data from database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc, jtable

I cant seems to load data into table despite being able to load column name dynamically. When I try to load data nothing appear despite the fact that Java Icon still showed on the taskbar. It doesn't look like there is anything wrong with GUI itself so I was wondering if opening a connection from constructor will cause logical error.I printed out the locals variables in the second for loop of populateTable method to check if data was passed into local variables and they did, so I don't know exactly what was causing this error.

here is the code for GUI:

```
public class WeatherFrame extends JFrame {

    private JPanel contentPane;
    private JTable table;
    HealthData health = new HealthData();
    private DefaultTableModel model;
    String[] columnNames = {"zipcode", "county", "city", "state", "year", "month","ageGroup",
                            "numOfVisits", "MonthlyMax", "MonthlyMin", "MonthlyNor"};

    /**
     * Launch the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    WeatherFrame frame = new WeatherFrame();
                    frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Create the frame.
     */
    public WeatherFrame() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setBounds(100, 100, 800, 300);
        contentPane = new JPanel();
        contentPane.setBounds(100, 100,750, 200);
        setContentPane(contentPane);
        contentPane.setLayout(null);

        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
        scrollPane.setBounds(6, 25, 788, 180);
        contentPane.add(scrollPane);

        model = new DefaultTableModel();
        populateTable();
        table = new JTable(model);

        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);

        JButton btnInsert = new JButton("insert");
        btnInsert.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnInsert.setBounds(315, 217, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnInsert);

        JButton btnDelete = new JButton("delete");
        btnDelete.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnDelete.setBounds(198, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnDelete);

        JButton btnSearch = new JButton("search");
        btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnSearch.setBounds(81, 243, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnSearch);

        JLabel lblWeatherTable = new JLabel("Weather Table");
        lblWeatherTable.setBounds(149, 6, 107, 16);
        contentPane.add(lblWeatherTable);

        JButton btnNext = new JButton("update");
        btnNext.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            }
        });
        btnNext.setBounds(198, 217, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnNext);

        JButton btnRefresh = new JButton("refresh");
        btnRefresh.setBounds(81, 217, 117, 29);
        contentPane.add(btnRefresh);
    }

    public void populateTable() {

        for(String name: columnNames)
            model.addColumn(name);

        ArrayList<Health> healthdata = new ArrayList<Health>();
        healthdata = health.showAllData();                                  
        model.addRow(healthdata.toArray()); 
    }
}
```

this is the constructor for the HealthData class

```
public HealthData(){
        try {
            /* Connect to database */
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, MySQLConfig.user, MySQLConfig.password);
            statement = connection.createStatement();
           data = new ArrayList<Health>();
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

this is the code for showAlldata method

```
public ArrayList<Health> showAllData(){
        ArrayList<Health> list = new ArrayList<Health>();
        try {
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcURL, MySQLConfig.user, MySQLConfig.password);
            Statement stmt = connection.createStatement();
            ResultSet result = stmt.executeQuery(SELECT_ALL_QUERY);


            /* Get and print out data from health table : zipcode, county, city, state, year, month, ageGroup, numberOfVisits, MMax, MMin, MNor */
            while(result.next()){
                Health data = new Health();
                int zipcode = result.getInt(1);
                data.setZipCode(zipcode);
                String county = result.getString(2);
                data.setCounty(county);
                String city = result.getString(3);
                data.setCity(city);
                String state = result.getString(4);
                data.setState(state);
                int year = result.getInt(5);
                data.setYear(year);
                int month = result.getInt(6);
                data.setMonth(month);
                String ageGroup = result.getString(7);
                data.setAgeGroup(ageGroup);
                int numOfVisits = result.getInt(8);
                data.setNumOfVisits(numOfVisits);
                float MMax = result.getFloat(9);
                data.setMMax(MMax);
                float MMin = result.getFloat(10);
                data.setMMin(MMin);
                float MNor = result.getFloat(11);
                data.setMNor(MNor);
                list.add(data);     
                connection.close()
                stmt.close();   
            }   

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list;
    }
```

Can someone suggest a solution for solving this problem. Thank you in advance for helping. I already posted a question about this but this question is up to date with required codes.

I edit the code to make only one call to showAlldata and also close connection and statement, however, the same error still persist

Comment: Your code is still using null layouts.

Comment: yes,  I can change it after I fix this problem, but I don't think the null layout is the problem here

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Yes, I will modify the layout after Im able to load data into table, Im just trying to test the table here, and it doesn't work, I was able to execute the code to show table with column names before loading data in though.

Comment: You're repeatedly calling `showAllData`.  Call it once and maintain a reference to the `List` of data it returns, use this `List` to populate the table.  Without the database, you table updates just fine in my testing.

Comment: You're also not managing your resources properly. You should be closing both the `Statement` and `ResultSet` once you've finished with it. See [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for more details

Comment: oh the HealthData class is not mine, it is from a class project, thank for the input, I will inform the person who wrote it to update it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96753/discussion-between-khoavo-and-madprogrammer).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void populateTable() {

        model = new DefaultTableModel(){

            @Override
            public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int column) {
               //all cells false
               return false;
            }
        };

        for(String name: columnNames)
            model.addColumn(name);
        ArrayList<Health> temp = new ArrayList<Health>();
        temp = health.showAllData();
        for(int i = 0; i< temp.size(); i++) {
            Object[] data = {temp.get(i).getZipCode(), temp.get(i).getCounty(), temp.get(i).getCounty(), temp.get(i).getState(),temp.get(i).getYear(),
                             temp.get(i).getMonth(), temp.get(i).getAgeGroup(), temp.get(i).getNumOfVisits(), temp.get(i).getMMax(), temp.get(i).getMMin(), temp.get(i).getMNor()};
            model.addRow(data);
        }
    }
```

thank you very much for helping, I solved this question by modifying my populateTable Method as above.